Lenovo TB X505F
a known, 90 years old, has forgotten PIN and Google account. He still has a bill. Even if the device is already about 4 years old, he would like to use it. How can he unlock tablet. Is that possible without much effort?


Verify Account -
Log in with your Google account
This device was reset. To proceed, log in with the Google account that was previously synced with this device.


The image shows that the device has been "reset" (factory reset)? What you face is the Factory Reset Protection (FRP).

As Robert commented, looks like the tablet has been reset. Not sure by "He still has a bill", but if the bill is in the tablet's storage, then most likely it's already gone, which How to recover a deleted file from /data partition on a rooted phone? might be more helpful.

@AndrewT. "he still has the bill" I assume was meant in a way that the old man can proof ownership of the tablet. For Apple devices such an ownership proof is often necessary if you go to an Apple store. For Android devices it is not very common to my knowledge that you need the bill.
